# error al ingresar nombres con ñ en laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

laravel me esta mostrando este error al ingresar registros que contengan la ñ y por supuesto tildes.

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE3\xB1es' for column 'names' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `clients` (`cedula`, `names`, `email`) values (5454545, Pablito Nu�es, email@dominio.com))
```

la base de datos esta en utf8_gereal_ci

use el siguiente mutator:

```
public function setNamesAttribute($value)
    {
        //$this->attributes['names'] = strtr($value, 'àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ', 'aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY');

    }
```

pero este me devuelve "YA" en vez de "n".

algun consejo para resolver esto??

Comment: No creo que el problema sea Laravel, ¿MySQL o Postgres?

Comment: Lo que parece indicar el mensaje de error es que **¡has declarado la columna `names` de tipo `datetime` !**: `Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE3\xB1es' for column 'names'`

Comment: Como dice @A.Cedano el problema es la definición del campo, luego en mutator estas usando strtr con unos caracteres que son multibyte, necesitas usar las funciones mb_ en este caso http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strstr.php

Comment: gracias por comentar. la columna "names" esta definida como varchar, y la imput como text

Comment: ¿Si intentas ingresar un nombre si caracteres especiales funciona?

Comment: si amigo, todo funciona perfecto.

Comment: Es muy extraño que está dando ese error... no entiendo. Por otra parte, ¿los valores de tipo string no deberían ir rodeados de comillas simples en el INSERT INTO... : `.... 'Pablito Nu�es', 'email@dominio.com'` ?

Comment: Puedes poner el contenido del archivo **/tu_proyecto/config/database.php** ?? aparte de la base de datos las tablas tambien estan en utf8, la recomendacion para mysql es **utf8mb4**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pueden ocurrir varias cosas, pero para todo hay solución:

**1 - Base de datos**

Tienes la base de datos en un idioma que no soporta ñ o tildes , por lo general lo mejor es usar *utf8_spanish_ci* , para sacarte de esos problemas.

**2 - PHP**

Este error previamente a la inserción se puede parsear con el código :

***Formato mysql***

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663255/php-mysql-insert-into-utf-8)

***Formato PDO***

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:$connstr",  $user, $password);
$dbh->exec("set names utf8");
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361459/php-pdo-charset-set-names)

***Formato mysqli***

```
mysqli_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```